# how to extract whole table data using while loop in asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net

I want to retrieve the whole table data and than display it on my form i have tried to fetch the data and i am successful but i am getting a problem in fetching because it is displaying the last fetched row in all asp:label. here is my code.

```
while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            tittle.Text = reader["Title"].ToString();
            desc.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();

            image2.ImageUrl = "~/Adminpanal/";
            image2.ImageUrl += reader["Thumbnail"].ToString();

            portfolioimg.NavigateUrl="~/Adminpanal/";
            portfolioimg.NavigateUrl += reader["image"].ToString();

            fancybox.NavigateUrl = "~/Adminpanal/";
            fancybox.NavigateUrl += reader["LinkUrl"].ToString();

            tittle1.Text = reader["Title"].ToString();
            desc1.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();

            image3.ImageUrl = "~/Adminpanal/";
            image3.ImageUrl += reader["Thumbnail"].ToString();

            HyperLink4.NavigateUrl = "~/Adminpanal/";
            HyperLink4.NavigateUrl += reader["image"].ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
```

here is my table structure
[image: Database image]

here is the snapshot[image: website snapshot]
can you see the my second website is appearing twice while i have two database entries you can see by watching table snapshot

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "it is displaying the last fetched row in all form here is my code."?

Comment: oh sorry means that it fetched the last row of table and display it in every asp:label

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your page?

Comment: yea sure i am going to upload it

Comment: You need to use a asp:repeater or something similar... otherwise you just have one set of values and you keep overwriting them in the your loop... so yes it makes sense it will only show the last item.

Comment: thanks @MikeSmithDev but will you please refer me some link or example i will be thankful to you

Comment: @Vicky [MSDN is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for showing me the path thanks a lot @MikeSmithDev